# How to get selenium to webscrape the 2nd page of results in a popup window

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape various pages of results. The first page works fine but when I switch to the next page, unfortunately,it just webscrapes the first page of results again. The results dont return a new URL so that way doesn't work but rather its a window on top of the url opened page. I also cant seem to figure out how to append the results of the first page to add the second page, they come out as separate lists. Below is the code I have.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#original webscraping code to get the names of locations from page 1
url = r'https://autochek.africa/en/ng/fix-your-car/service/scheduled-car-service'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
xpath_get_locations = r'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[7]/div/label'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_get_locations).click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


location_results = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jsx-1642469937 state'})]

print(location_results)
time.sleep(3)

#finished page 1, finding the next button to go to page 2
xpath_find_next_button = r'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[13]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_find_next_button).click()

#getting the locations from page 2
second_page_results = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jsx-1642469937 state'})]



print(second_page_results)
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: you have to run again `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')` to work with next page(s)

Answer (score 1):

After loading new page or running some JavaScript code on page you have to run again

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

to work with new HTML.

---

Or skip `BeautifulSoup` and do all in `Selenium`.

Use `find_elements_...` with char `s` in word `elements`.

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="jsx-1642469937 state"]')

location_result = [i.text for i in items]
```

---

**By The Way:**

(`xpath` doesn't need prefix `r` because it doesn't use `\` )

Shorter and more readable `xpath`.

```
#xpath_get_locations = r'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[7]/div/label'

xpath_get_locations = '//label[text()="Drop-off at Autochek location"]'
```

And it would be simpler to use button `Next >` instead of searching buttons `2`, `3`, etc.

```
xpath_find_next_button = '//li[@class="next-li"]/a'
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code which uses `while`-loop to visit all pages.

I added module `webdriver_manager` which automatically downloads (fresh) driver for browser.

I use `find_elemens(By.XPATH, ...)` because `find_elemens_by_xpath(...)` is `deprecated`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

import time
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

# ---

url = 'https://autochek.africa/en/ng/fix-your-car/service/scheduled-car-service'
driver.get(url)

#xpath_get_locations = r'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[7]/div/label'
xpath_get_locations = '//label[text()="Drop-off at Autochek location"]'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_get_locations).click()

# ---

all_locations = []

while True:
    
    # --- get locations on page
    
    time.sleep(1) # sometimes `JavaScript` may need time to add new items (and you can't catch it with `WebDriverWait`)

    #items = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jsx-1642469937 state'})
    items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="jsx-1642469937 state"]')

    #soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    locations = [i.text for i in items]

    print(locations)
    print('-------')

    all_locations += locations
    
    # --- find button `next >` and try to click it 
    
    #xpath_find_next_button = r'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[13]'
    xpath_find_next_button = '//li[@class="next-li"]/a'

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_find_next_button).click()
    except:
        break  # exit loop
    
# ---

#driver.close()
```

Comment: Wow! thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense. Im obviously fairly new to this so thank you for the added explanations